# How to combine transclusion, replace and ngIf?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular 1.2.9 (latest stable at the time of writing). Minimal example of a directive that shows the problem:

```
myApp.directive('panel', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-if="showPanel" ng-transclude></div>',
    };
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3782/ Open the console and toggle the checkbox. It complains about an orphaned `ngTransclude`. As far as I can tell, this has something to do with the fact that `ngIf` also uses transclusion.

I'm not sure if this is an Angular bug or whether I'm doing something wrong.

I can think of some workarounds:

- Remove `ng-if` and implement its behaviour manually. But its implementation is several dozen lines, and I don't understand it well enough to reproduce it with confidence.
- Stop using replace, stop using a template, and set all needed styles and classes on the directive's element itself. This would require a bunch of JavaScript code to reproduce the template's structure in code.

Constraints on any solution/workaround:

- Because I'm using a flexbox, the generated element must be a direct child of the directive's parent element (i.e. what replace does).
- The `ngIf` cannot be moved outside the directive, because in reality I'm using a condition that relies on the directive's isolate scope.

Is there a better way to make this just work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`.

If, for some reason, you absolutely need to remove the element from the DOM tree, then a custom solution isn't that difficult to create. Transclusion is just a simple function call and the rest boils down to watching a value and adding / removing the element from the DOM:

```
return {
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        showPanel: '='
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
        var parent = element.parent(),
            insertAfter = angular.element(element[0].previousSibling);

        transclude(scope.$parent, function (clone) {    
           element.append(clone);
        });

        scope.$watch('showPanel', function(value) {
            if (value) {         
              $animate.enter(element, parent, insertAfter);  
            }
            else {
              $animate.leave(element);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJ8UE/). You might want to tweak it for your situation, of course. In case you don't want animation just use the respective methods of `angular.element`.

Comment: I went with `ng-show` eventually. If the performance hit becomes a problem, I can always revisit.